# Concavity when 2nd derivative is zero

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was self-studying for a CLEP calculus exam when the following problem came up. It basically asks you to sketch a graph of a function based on the information given.

[image]

My question is about the part of the graph where $-1 < x < 1$. Since $f''(x) = 0$ in this interval, doesn't that mean that the original function f(x) should be linear here (i.e. a straight line)? But the book's provided answer clearly shows a concave-up curve in this interval, which confused me.

Is the book's answer wrong? Or am I misunderstanding something? Thank you.

Comment: You are correct: $f'(x)$ must be constant on $-1<x<1$.

Comment: Based on the structure of the question and their answer, it seems like they meant to say $ f''(x) > 0 $ instead of $ f''(x) = 0 $.

Comment: It must be $f''(x)\color{red}>0$ for $-1<x<1$ There is a typo in your book.

Comment: If the graph is correct then it should also say that $f^{\prime\prime}(x)<0$ for $1<x<4$.